# iOS Draw the same shape multiple times

Tags: ios, image, drawing

need some help with quartz 2d, it is completely new for me.

Basically my app needs to follow the touch, draw that line starting from center multiple times. The issue is that it has to be dynamic and the lines have to be on equally spread( kind of like octopus starting from center). The way I have it on android is that I remember the shape paths in array, than draw it multiple times with rotating the coordinate system, but I cannot figure out how to do it on iOS.

My rotate function

```
- (void) rotateContext:(int)angle 
{


    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.center.x, self.center.y);
    CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), radians(angle));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -self.center.x, -self.center.y);


}
```

It only works if I try do do it in drawRect(), and it rotates all the paths with it.

Can you please suggest me a good way to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: If you are going to work with a same shape that are being drawn repeatedly on the screen, you should work with CGLayers. [See the official documentation for more info.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_layers/dq_layers.html)

Answer (score 0):

This can lead you to a solution:
*(maybe it even compiles)*

```
/* setup the context */
UIBezierPath *bpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
UIBezierPath *subpath =
[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:<#some rect#>];
[bpath appendPath:subpath];
/* add more stuff to the path as you wish */

bezierPath.lineWidth = 2;     
/* draw the same path rotated multiple times */
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    [bpath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2 * i)];
    [bpath stroke];
}
/* teardown the context */
```

Rotating a bezier is tricky, you'll need to apply a more complex transformation depending on the results you expect.

Those bezier paths objects can be stored in an array or whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks, looks quite promising, will try in the morning! Do you know a good resource to understand the context part? I read it on apple website but it is a bit confusing.

Comment: Is Google banned on your country or what? Just search "Core Graphics" followed by books, tutorials, etc. and you'll see a lot of resources. And read again Apple docs, they are not confusing, it's just that low level graphics are not easy.